# If $A$ is a $3\times 3$ complex matrix such that $A^3=-I$, then $A$ has distinct eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $3\times 3$ complex matrix such that $A^3=-I$

How to show that $A$ has distinct eigenvalues?

What if i consider $A=-I?$ Isn't then -1 becoming the only eigen value?

Comment: You just have found a counterexample. But maybe you meant to say: complex matrix such that there is at least one non-real entry. Or something to that effect.

Comment: Let $m_A(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$, then $m_A(x)|x^3 + 1$, may be this can help.

Comment: @Raskolnikov the question just tell A be a complex $3\times 3$ matrix such that A^3=-I and i need to verify whether the statement "A has three distinct eigenvalues" is correct. It is incorrect right?

Comment: @Raskolnikov: Your suggested reformulation doesn't change much since $A = e^{i\pi/3} I$ has $A^3 = - I$ but only one eigenvalue. In fact, any polynomial is satisfied by a matrix $\lambda I$ where $\lambda$ is one of the roots of the polynomial...

Comment: @Mike: Nice catch.

Comment: @Mike Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 3):

This question was answered (more like confirmed, actually) in the comments.

For any $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ the matrix equation $A^3 = \lambda I$ has $A = \mu I$ as a solution where $\mu$ is one of the cube roots of $\lambda$. More generally, for any nonzero polynomial $p(z) \in \mathbb{C}[z]
$, the matrix equation $p(A) = 0$ has a solution $A = \mu I$ where $\mu$ is one of the roots of $p(z)$. Matrices of the form $\mu I$, far from having distinct eigenvlaues, have only one eigenvalue, that is to say $\mu$.